# return int to use as variable in swiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode12

I have a func that return a int.

```
func pval() -> Int {
    
      var p = 1
    
    let now = Date()
    let day1 = Date.parse("2021-03-23")
    let day2 = Date.parse("2021-04-23")
    let day3 = Date.parse("2021-05-23")
    let day4 = Date.parse("2021-06-23")
        

    if now > day1 && now < day2 {
        p = 2
    }else if now > day2 && now < day3 {
        p = 3
    }else if now > day3 && now < day4 {
        p = 4
    }
        return p
       
    }
    
    var p = pval()
```

I would like to make the returned int a variable but I am getting the error
"Cannot use instance member 'pval' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available". printing p works but trying to make it a variable does not. Does anyone know how I could fix this??

Answer (score 1):

I just used oval as my var instead of redeclaring it